# Get Firebase Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created when using React-hooks-testing-library with jest

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I using Firebase auth in React, and I try to test it with `react-hooks-testing-library`. The code I write is working. But when I try to test with `react-hooks-testing-library` I get this error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created
> , call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

Here is my actual code:

**useAuth.tsx**

```
const defaultValue = {
     .. some value here
}

const AuthContext = createContext(defaultValue)

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
    const auth = useFirebaseAuth()

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={auth}
        >
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

// I will like to test the function and behaviour inside this hooks, useFirebaseAuth() here
export default function useFirebaseAuth() {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  
    const loginWithEmailPassword = (email: string, password: string) => {

        const auth = getAuth() // the error point to this line!!! 

        //this code I followed the Firebase docs    
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then(res => {

            }).catch(error => {

            })
    }

    const signUpWithEmailPassword = () => {

    }


    return {
        user,
        loginWithEmailPassword,
        signUpWithEmailPassword
    }

}

export { useAuth, AuthContextProvider }
```

Inside this hook will have 3 item, which `user`, `loginWithEmailPassword`, `signUpWithEmailPassword`

**Here is my test**

**useAuth.test.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks/native'
import useFirebaseAuth from '../useAuth';

// Here I tried to mock the auth function of Firebase
jest.mock('firebase/app', () => {
    return {
        App: () => ({
            app: mockGetApp
        }),
        auth: () => ({
            signInWithEmailAndPassword: mockSignIn,
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword: mockSignUp
        })
    }
})

const mockInitializeFirebase = jest.fn()
const mockSignUp = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
const mockSignIn = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
const mockGetApp = jest.fn()

jest.mock('../../utils/initAuth', () => {
    return {
        app: mockInitializeFirebase
    }
})

describe('useAuth Hooks testing', () => {

    test('Login with Email and Password', () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useFirebaseAuth())

        console.log(result)

        //arrange it, confirm the initial state 
        expect(result.current.user).toBe(null)
        expect(typeof result.current.loginWithEmailPassword).toBe('function')
        expect(typeof result.current.signUpWithEmailPassword).toBe('function')

        const email = 'abc@gmail.com'
        const password = '123456'
        // here act
        act(() => {
            // The problem come from this line
            result.current.loginWithEmailPassword(email, password)
        })
        // here assert 
        expect(mockSignIn).toBeCalledWith(email, password)

    })
})
```

So when I fired the `loginWithEmailPassword(email,password)` function, it keep showing `No Firebase App error`. But in my project I already have this file, which is initialize the Firebase app already.

**./initFirebase.tsx**, here  already initialize the app, and called it in `index.tsx`

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import getEnvVars from '../environment'

const env = getEnvVars()

interface firebaseType {
    apiKey: string,
    authDomain: string,
    projectId: string,
    messagingSenderId: string
}

let firebaseConfig: firebaseType;

if (env !== null) {

    const { apiKey, authDomain, projectId, messagingSenderId } = env
    firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: apiKey,
        authDomain: authDomain,
        projectId: projectId,
        messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId
    };
}

export const initFirebase = () => {
    if (getApps().length === 0) {
        initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    } else {
        getApp()
    }
}
```

So the error is only happened in test, so I think I should mock the `initializeApp` function and call it somewhere in the test. But I dont know how to do that.

I just get started in `testing` field. Somebody that have experience please give some help.

Here is the question:

1. What happened to my code and test that make the error occured?
2. What should I do in order to solve this error?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by mock it like this:

```
const mockSignUp = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
        user: {
            uid: "fakeuid",
        },
    });
})
const mockSignIn = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
    user: {
        uid: "fakeUid"
    }
}))

const mockGetAuth = jest.fn()

jest.mock('firebase/auth', () => {
    return {
        getAuth: () => mockGetAuth,
        signInWithEmailAndPassword: () => mockSignIn,
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword: () => mockSignUp
    }
})
```

Noted by this:

`getAuth: ()=> mockGetAuth` the 3 function there, this will mock as `getAuth()` in firebase to the mockGetAuth function I defined.

Then in test I can called the mock function like this:

```
// here check the mock function 
mockSignIn(mockGetAuth, email, password)
expect(mockSignIn).toBeCalledWith(mockGetAuth, email, password)
```

Comment: Would you happen to know the solution to a simliar problem I'm having descrived here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72995101/how-do-i-know-what-should-be-added-as-a-provider-or-import-in-my-jasmine-unit-te/72995471#72995471

I've fixed the initial issue, now I'm getting this error:
Failed: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
error properties: Object({ code: 'app/no-app', customData: Object({ appName: '[DEFAULT]' }) })
 may be because of this line:
  userCollection = collection(getFirestore(getApp()), 'users');