# How do I know what should be added as a provider or import in my Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to unit tests and I haven't been able to find a clear and concise explanation of what gets added as a provider vs import in my spec.ts.  I keep getting the same error no matter what I try.

Here's my service class:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, UserCredential } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { signOut } from '@firebase/auth';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { DocumentData, DocumentReference } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  userCollection = collection(getFirestore(getApp()), 'users');

  constructor(private auth: Auth,
    private router: Router,
    private alertController: AlertController) { }

  async register(registrationForm: FormGroup): Promise<UserCredential> {
    return await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, registrationForm.value.email, registrationForm.value.password);
  }

  async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserCredential> {
    return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password);
  }

  logout(): Promise<void> {
    return signOut(this.auth);
  }

  async authenticationAlert(message: any, header: string, route: string): Promise<void> {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      subHeader: `${header}`,
      message: `${message}`,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          role: 'Ok',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(`${route}`);
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }

  saveProfile(uid: string, email: string, displayName: string): Promise<DocumentReference<DocumentData>> {
    return addDoc(this.userCollection, {uid, email, displayName});
  }
}
```

Here's the spec:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { signOut } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { addDoc, collection, DocumentReference, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, RouterTestingModule,],
      providers: [AuthService]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And this is the error I keep getting:

```js
AuthService > should be created
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthService -> Auth -> Auth]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Auth!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'AuthService', 'Auth', 'Auth' ] })
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthService -> Auth -> Auth]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Auth!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:9081:27)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:9248:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:9248:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:4868:33)
    at ɵɵinject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:4872:12)
    at Object.factory (ng:///AuthService/ɵfac.js:4:39)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:9343:35)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:9237:33)
    at NgModuleRef.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:22399:33)
    at TestBedRender3.inject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs:26537:52)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/services/auth.service.spec.ts:22:21)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:409:30)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:303:43)
```

Additionally, I'm getting this error in ever spec.ts on every component that imports the AuthService.

I'm not sure how to determine out of all of my imports which ones I'll have to include in the spec file.  And how do I determine if they get injected as a provider or import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gets added to imports are `modules` and what gets added to `providers` are services. Some `modules` export a `provider/service` in their `exports` field and therefore you can add a module to the `imports` section and then be able to inject the exported service in the constructor and Angular will know how to construct it.

The issue you're facing is that Angular does not know how to create `Auth` and `AlertController` injected into the service. It knows how to create `Router` because of the `RouterTestingModule`.

For a quick unblock, try this:

```
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;
  // create mocks
  let mockAuth: jasmine.SpyObj<Auth>;
  let mockAlertController: jasmine.SpyObj<AlertController>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // create spy objects and add public methods in the 2nd argument as a string
    mockAuth = jasmine.crateSpyObj<Auth>('Auth', {}, {});
    mockAlertController = jasmine.createSpyObj<AlertController>('AlertController', ['create']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, RouterTestingModule,],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        // give the fake services for the real ones
        { provide: Auth, useValue: mockAuth },
        { provide: AlertController, useValue: mockAlertController }
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Check out this resource: https://testing-angular.com/testing-components-depending-on-services/#testing-components-depending-on-services. There is also a section of `Testing Services` but basically you need to mock all external dependencies.

Comment: After your suggestion I'm getting the following: FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app). error properties: Object({ code: 'app/no-app', customData: Object({ appName: '[DEFAULT]' }) }) I can't find any documentation on how to handle this in unit tests.

Comment: Sorry, I am not experienced with FireBase. This answer uses Jest and it seems like they mocked it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69017810/7365461. Maybe you can try something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You get the `NullInjectorError: No provider for Auth!` error, because the `AuthService` injects the `private auth: Auth` variable in his constructor. In your `configureTestingModule` only `AuthService` provided.

If your goal is to write a Unit test for `AuthService` you need to provide mocked objects for all the three dependencies injected in it, I mean for followings:

```
private auth: Auth,
private router: Router,
private alertController: AlertController
```

You can find more options about how to do this here:
https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#services-with-dependencies.

For example if we would like provide a mock for the `alertController` the `TestBed` configuration would look similar to this:

```
// create a spy object for alertController.create() function
const alertControllerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AlertController', ['create']);
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ 
             ReactiveFormsModule, 
             FormsModule, 
             RouterTestingModule
           ],
  providers: [
              AuthService, 
              { provide: AlertController, useValue: alertControllerSpy},
              // here be should provided a mocked object for the other depedencies
             ]
});
```

Comment: After your suggestion I'm getting the following:
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
error properties: Object({ code: 'app/no-app', customData: Object({ appName: '[DEFAULT]' }) })
I can't find any documentation on how to handle this in unit tests.

Comment: I think it is because your tested code imports `{getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'` and they are called in your tested code. When they are called through the unit test, the application itself is not bootstrapped, only the service instance is created. It follows, that `App.initializeApp()` is not called, but the `getFirestore, collection, addDoc` methods are called at some point, this leads to the error. To handle this issue the `getFirestore, collection, addDoc`  methods need to be mocked.

Comment: But the challenge is, that this can not be done directly. I think a wrapper service is needed for them, this service could be injected through constructor in the application and the methods of it could be overdefined with mocks.